# How to play low b note on soprano recorder

Tags: recorder

is it possible to play low B (below middle C) on soprano recorder? If it is possible, how to play it? Do you have the chart? (hole)

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

By design, the lowest note on a soprano recorder is C5 (which is in fact *an octave above* middle C). And unlike the high end, the low end of a wind instrument's range can't be arbitrarily extended through agressive overblowing or something, so this might well be answered “it's just not possible”.

However, a B4 can actually be intoned, if badly, by partially covering the *end hole* of the recorder, in combination with very low blowing pressure.

So, just play the normal C with all standard holes covered and then also close the end hole partially. When playing while seated, this can be done with the knee.

I think there are also extended instruments available with an extra keyed hole that facilitates playing notes a little below the proper range.

An alternative that's even more awkward is to slightly extend the *length* of the instrument. Unless your recorder is one-piece, this can be accomplished by not-quite-properly plugging it together. Trouble is, this will change *all* notes in a hard-to-predict way.

The proper thing to do IMO, if you need notes like B, is to play the whole piece on an alto recorder instead.

Comment: Upvoted, especially for the mention of the bell key, which isn't something a lot of recorder players seem to be aware of (admittedly, it isn't something easily available). Strictly speaking, the point of the bell key is to play several *high register* notes accurately, although it can be creatively abused. Would upvote again for the final paragraph - playing outside normal range is likely to be out of tune even in the best of circumstances.

Comment: The lowest note on a soprano is C5, not C4 - middle C, for that you'd need a tenor recorder and the same discussion applies, although getting that low B on a tenor is a real trick.

Comment: @ohmi you're right, I neglected the “transposing” clef.

Comment: We could extend this to consider the semi-official way of getting an extra low semitone out if the larger saxophones which is to, literally, 'put your foot in it'.